# Is it possible that a new book could be added to the Bible?

Tags: bible

In my early years as a Christian I was taught that Revelation 22:18-20 was a warning that the Bible could not be added to or taken away from.  However reasonable study of this scripture bears out that the verse is talking about the book of Revelation only.
Considering that Christianity spent three quarters of it's history without a ratified Canon, and that there are certainly prophets and apostles leading the church today, what would it take for the writing of a modern prophet or apostle to be elevated to scripture?

Comment: Who exactly are you asking? Because, you know, LDS do/did exactly what you propose.

Comment: hmm good thought, but are LDS Christians?

Comment: Yes (too bad three-letter comments are not allowed ;-) )

Comment: Also, it doesn't matter, because the answer may or may not differ from denomination to denomination. LDS was just an example I happen to know well.